# Is it possible to parse blockfile_000000 from system channel?

Tags: parsing, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I’m not being able to obtain the config block from the system channel of my network by using “peer channel fetch config”, is it possible to extract it from the file located in the folder /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains/sys-channel /blockfile_000000 in the orderer?
I tried to decode it using

```
$ configtxlator proto_decode --input ./blockfile_000000 --type common.Block
```

But I’m getting an error:

```
config**your text**txlator: error: Error decoding: error unmarshalling: proto: can't skip unknown wire type 4
```

I also tried:

```
azureuser@cas-orderers:~/orderer1$ configtxgen -inspectBlock ./blockfile_000000
2023-03-31 06:05:53.527 UTC 0001 INFO [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> Loading configuration
2023-03-31 06:05:53.528 UTC 0002 INFO [common.tools.configtxgen] doInspectBlock -> Inspecting block
2023-03-31 06:05:53.528 UTC 0003 INFO [common.tools.configtxgen] doInspectBlock -> Parsing genesis block
2023-03-31 06:05:53.528 UTC 0004 FATA [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> Error on inspectBlock: error unmarshalling to block: error unmarshalling Block: proto: can't skip unknown wire type 4
```

Without any result. Is there any other way to do this?

Tried using configtxlator aznd configtxgen -inspectBlock witout results.

Comment: Maybe  the block file is corrupted or is not a valid protobuf-encoded block file. Check the file and ensure this file is not corrupt.

Comment: what tool can I use to verify if it is corrupt or not?

Comment: you can use  `protoc ` tool. First of all install `protobuf-compiler`  and than change, then install the `.proto` file for the fabric common
after then `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/main/protos/common/common.proto` in this command